# WCF AddressAccessDeniedException

Tags: c#, wcf

I am new to WCF.

I created a WCF service which was working , but when I try to host it in a console application, it is giving me an exception:

`AddressAccessDeniedException`

```
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ISampleService), new BasicHttpBinding(),"http://localhost:8080/evals/basic");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on Visual Studio and run it as Administrator.